# Is there any risk to read/write the same file content from different 'sessions' in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I'm new in `Node JS` and i wonder if under mentioned snippets of code has *multisession* problem.

Consider I have Node JS server (`express`) and I listen on some `POST` request:

```
app.post('/sync/:method', onPostRequest);

var onPostRequest = function(req,res){

  // parse request and fetch email list
  var emails = [....]; // pseudocode 

  doJob(emails);

  res.status(200).end('OK');
}

 function doJob(_emails){

    try {
        emailsFromFile = fs.readFileSync(FILE_PATH, "utf8") || {};

        if(_.isString(oldEmails)){
           emailsFromFile = JSON.parse(emailsFromFile); 
        }

         _emails.forEach(function(_email){

            if( !emailsFromFile[_email] ){
               emailsFromFile[_email] = 0;
            }
            else{
               emailsFromFile[_email] += 1;
            }                
        });

        // write object back
        fs.writeFileSync(FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(emailsFromFile));

    } catch (e) {
         console.error(e);            
    };
 }
```

So  `doJob` method receives `_emails` list and I update (counter +1) these emails from object `emailsFromFile` loaded from file.

Consider I got 2 requests at the same time and it triggers `doJob` twice. I afraid that when **one request** loaded `emailsFromFile` from file, the **second request** might change file content.

Can anybody spread the light on this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the code in the `doJob()` function is all synchronous, there is no risk of multiple requests causing a concurrency problem.

If you were using async IO in that function, then there would be possible concurrency issues.

To explain, Javascript in node.js is single threaded.  So, there is only one thread of Javascript execution running at a time and that thread of execution runs until it returns back to the event loop.  So, any sequence of entirely synchronous code like you have in `doJob()` will run to completion without interruption.

If, on the other hand, you use any asynchronous operations such as `fs.readFile()` instead of `fs.readFileSync()`, then that thread of execution will return back to the event loop at the point you call `fs.readFileSync()` and another request can be run while it is reading the file.  If that were the case, then you could end up with two requests conflicting over the same file.  In that case, you would have to implement some form of concurrency protection (some sort of flag or queue).  This is the type of thing that databases offer lots of features for.

I have a node.js app running on a Raspberry Pi that uses lots of async file I/O and I can have conflicts with that code from multiple requests.  I solved it by setting a flag anytime I'm writing to a specific file and any other requests that want to write to that file first check that flag and if it is set, those requests going into my own queue are then served when the prior request finishes its write operation.  There are many other ways to solve that too.  If this happens in a lot of places, then it's probably worth just getting a database that offers features for this type of write contention.

Comment: the problem is: when one 'session' loaded email counter, lets say `3`, and run +1, before it stores it back, other session updated this counter already, so it actually should be 5, but 1st session stores 4 intead

Comment: @MaximShoustin - Please read my answer again.  No other request can run while `doJob()` is running.  So nothing else can change the session while `doJob()` is running.  This is because `doJob()` is entirely synchronous code.  If it was async, that would be a different story.